# Installing psycopg-binary on Docker pipenv, got the error does not found Python 3.8 on the system

Tags: python, docker, pipenv, pyenv

I am using pipenv, Docker 19.03.8, django 3.0.1 framework, and python 3.8.2 (checked by python --version). When I am trying to install psycopg2-binary by using `$ docker-compose exec web pipenv install psycopg2-binary==2.8.3`, I got the error:

```
Warning: Python 3.8 was not found on your system…
Neither 'pyenv' nor 'asdf' could be found to install Python.
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
$ pipenv --python path/to/python
```

My Pipfile contains:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM python:3.8
```

docker-compose.yml contains:

```
version: '3.8'
```

I have tried installing `pyenv` and `asdf` (as suggested in the error message) via `brew`, and still got the error.
I have also tried specifying the version by using `$ pipenv --python /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3` and `$ pipenv --python /Users/dhafinrazaq/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/bin/python3.8`, but still get the error.

Comment: You are confusing your host machine with the docker container. The docker container does not have any notion of the software on your MacOS machine. Inside the docker container it's also not required to use environments. Just install the regular packages with `pip` and run `python`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ docker-compose exec web pipenv --python /usr/bin/python3 install psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
```

you can give your python installation path like i have given above. I have bolded that part in above code. it worked for me. **--python /usr/bin/python3** add this part.